# How to display debug info or console.log equivalent in Lua

Tags: debugging, lua, console.log, love2d

I am creating many games using Lua and LOVE2D, but whenever I implement a new function and want to test it out, or simply want to know a value of a variable in Lua, I either display it on the game screen or just hope that it works.

Now my question is...
IS THERE A WAY TO DISPLAY SOME INFO, such as A VARIABLE VALUE or something else into the terminal or somewhere else? Just like `console.log` in javascript which displays some content in the javascript console in the browser. So, is there a way to do this is Lua?? using LOVE2D?

I am using a Mac, so I have a `terminal` and not a command prompt. Is there a way to display some content there? Anywhere else would also be fine, I just need to see if those values are as expected or not.

Comment: `print( 'variable:', variable )` or http://neopallium.github.io/lualogging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `conf.lua` file to enable the console, then you should be able to use a standard `print()`. You can read the wiki entry [here](https://love2d.org/wiki/Config_Files).

**Note: You have to run Lua and Love2D via the terminal for this to work. Running Lua and Love2D like this is required for the print statements to show:**

```bash
/Applications/love.app/Contents/MacOS/love "/Users/myuser/Desktop/love2d-test-proj"
```

You just need to add a `conf.lua` file to the same location where your `main.lua`. Your file may be as simple as this:

```
function love.conf(t)
    t.console = true
end
```

But feel free to copy the whole configuration file from the above link and edit what you need.

I can't be completely sure about this, because I have no access to Mac, but the console is disabled by default and even on Windows, no prints are shown until you turn it on.

**Alternatively** You can also display debug info in the game itself like some games do.

What I like to do is add something like `debugVariable = {}` for logging events that happen in each loop and `debugPermanent = {}` for events that happen rarely. Possibly add convenience functions for writing to the variables:

```
function debugAddVariable(str)
  table.insert(debugVariable, str)
end
--..and similarly for debugPermanent
```

Now a function to draw our debug info:

```
function debugDraw()
  love.graphics.push()  --remember graphics state

  love.graphics.origin()  --clear any previous transforms

  love.graphics.setColor(--[[select color for debug info]])
  love.graphics.setFont(--[[select font for debug info]])

  for i, v in ipairs(debugPermanent) do
    love.graphics.print(v)
    love.graphics.translate(0, --[[fontHeight]])
  end
  for i, v in ipairs(debugVariable) do
    love.graphics.print(v)
    love.graphics.translate(0, --[[fontHeight]])
  end
  
  debugVariable = {}   --clear debugVariable to prepare it for the next loop
  love.graphics.pop()  --recall graphics state
end
```

And we just call this draw function at the end of our `love.draw()` and the texts should appear.

Obviously, this method can be refined further and further almost infinitely, displaying specific variables, and adding graphs for some other variables to clarify the information you want to show, but that's kind of outside of the scope of the question.

**Lastly** Feel free to check [here](https://love2d.org/wiki/Category:Libraries) for debug libraries submitted by users.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked for me even while using a MAC!